# Jquery/Javascript refresh and load different files on intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion

What I want to do is essentially have a web page that on one section refreshes and loads a different file of content every 10 seconds or so. I don't want to use an `<iframe>`. I have it close, as it works, but the files are displaying randomly instead of in order. I am sure there is a more appropriate way to do this but Jquery and Javascript is not my strong suit. If it helps, I am using Coldfusion.

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("##responsecontainer").load("content/1.cfm");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("##responsecontainer").load(‘content / 1. cfm’);
    }, 20000);
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("##responsecontainer").load("content/2.cfm");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("##responsecontainer").load(‘content / 2. cfm’);
    }, 30000);
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("##responsecontainer").load("content/3.cfm");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("##responsecontainer").load(‘content / 3. cfm’);
    }, 60000);
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

});
```

This is the simple DIV with ID displaying the content from the other files:

```
<div id="responsecontainer" ></div>
```

I appreciate any help!

**UPDATE: Need additional help.**

So I couldn't get any of those solutions to display. However, I found this and it works great.

```
$(function () {

var counter = 0,
    divs = $('#div1, #div2, #div3');

function showDiv () {
    divs.hide() // hide all divs
        .filter(function (index) { return index == counter % 3; }) // figure out correct div to show
        .show('fast'); // and show it

    counter++;
}; // function to loop through divs and show correct div

showDiv(); // show first div    

setInterval(function () {
    showDiv(); // show next div
}, 10 * 1000); // do this every 10 seconds    

});
```

However, I now need the content inside these divs to auto refresh (without refreshing whole page) because the data it is pulling from the db will be updated.
I do have all three divs inside it's own div if that helps.

To clarify, this is a web page that will be displayed on a wall monitor with changing content.

Comment: You probably want to replace those formatted quotes with straight quotes and (while not incorrect) merge the 3 `document.ready()` functions into one.

Comment: If there is a specific order that the files should be loaded, place the function that gets the next file as the second argument to the `load()` call on the previous one as this is how to set up a success callback with `.load()`.

Comment: Thanks! Could you show me an example?

Comment: `$("##responsecontainer).load("file1", function(){ $("##responsecontainer).load("file2", function(){$("##responsecontainer).load("file3)}) })`

Comment: Hmm..can't seem to get either of these to displaying anything at all.

Comment: You can't rely on setInterval to actually run in the intervals you specify. Just load all three at once with cfinclude then show/hide the divs. It's very unlikely for most users to sit there for 2 minutes anyway.

Comment: I got something to work for this, but now I need an additional step. See my updates in original post. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you are triggering 3 different intervals try to do it with only one like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var idx = 1;
  var time = 20000;
  var file = ["1.cfm","2.cfm","3.cfm"];
  $(“#responsecontainer”).load("content/1.cfm");
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                     $(“#responsecontainer”).load("content/" + file[idx]);
                     idx = (idx<file.length?idx++:0);
                  }, time);
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

Also having multiple `$(document).ready(function() {` is kinda wrong... and this solve that also.

Comment: Would I use the same DIV ID for this to display?  (It's not displaying anything)

Comment: Yes, you do, but I copied your code and modified its logic but not the names of the components... I fix it now, please try it now.

Answer (score -1):

You should start the next interval after the file successfully loaded.

```
  $(function(){
    var time = 3000,
    files = ["1.cfm","2.cfm","3.cfm"],
    ind=0,
    element=$('#responsecontainer');
    function refreshCont(){
        var int = setTimeout(function(){
            element.load('content/' + files[ind] , function(){
            ind = ind < files.length ? ind++ : 0;
            refreshCont();
            });
        }, time);
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```